# Xamarin ArrayAdapter doesn't work with int[]

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview with an array adapter. I need to show in that listview an int[], but it only works with string[]. Any idea?

This is my code:

```
int[] a = new int[20];

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, a[i]);

ListView list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
list.Adapter = adapter;
```

The `int i` is in for a cycle.

Comment: That code looks like you were only passing in the int value at index i, rather than the actually array, wouldn't it just be:

int[] a = new int[20];

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to string array,

```
string[] result = a.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray();

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, result[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IList`-based collection to allow for automatic C#/Java type conversions

```
var a = new List<int>() { 1,2,3 };
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, a);
ListView list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
list.Adapter = adapter;
```